# Converting Binary bits to the bytes array

Tags: java, arrays, binary, bit

I'm trying to flip a bit in the binary text given and change my binary string to byte array
the index of bit I'm flipping is a range between 0~63. I do not have any problems flipping 1~63. But whenever I flip the 0th index of the bit and change to byte some how I get 9 segments of the blocks. like this: (BF stands for before the flip, AF stands for After the flip)

Input is the string of binary of BF
Output is the string of binary of AF

BF:0100011001100001011000110110010101100010011011110110111101101011
AF:1100011001100001011000110110010101100010011011110110111101101011
Segment: 0 -58 97 99 101 98 111 111 107

Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 8 bytes

Here is my code for flipping the bit :

```
public static String flipBit(String s1, int num)
    {
        char[] arr = s1.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.print("BF:");
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        if(arr[num] == '1')
        {
        //  System.out.println("Hello");
            arr[num] = '0';
        }
        else 
            if(arr[num] == '0')
        {
        //  System.out.println("HI");
            arr[num] = '1';
        }
        
        return String.copyValueOf(arr);
    }
```

Here is my code for changing binary string to bytes:

```
    public static byte[] binaryToByte(String s1)
    {
        byte[] array = new BigInteger(s1,2).toByteArray();
        return array;
    }
```

Here is the main function:

```
String flipedBit = flipBit(plaintextBinary,0);
        
        System.out.println("AF:" + flipedBit);
        
        byte[] fbp = binaryToByte(flipedBit);
for(int i = 0; i<fbp.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(fbp[i] + " ");
        }

Cipher encrypt2 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        Key ky2 = new SecretKeySpec(key,"DES");
        encrypt2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,ky2);
        byte[] cbp = encrypt.doFinal(fbp);
```

Why I get 9 segments if I flip the only 0th index ?

Comment: Why don't you show the input, and expected output  and the bits you are inverting.

Comment: Where are you calling `javax.crypto`?

Comment: And I'm with @WJS.  Show the input to your function, the expected output and the actual output you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is your `BigInteger` conversion method.  The first byte is the sign bit so it is returning 9 bytes, the first being 0.

```
String s = "1100011001100001011000110110010101100010011011110110111101101011";
byte[] b = new BigInteger(s,2).toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

prints

```
[0, -58, 97, 99, 101, 98, 111, 111, 107]
```

From the JavaDoc for BigInteger

> Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element. The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, including at least one sign bit, which is (ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8)). (This representation is compatible with the (byte[]) constructor.)